# Can I get response headers from javascript?

Tags: javascript, web-services, web

```
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = "https://code.jquery.com/jquery.js";
document.documentElement.appendChild(script);
```

I load it, But I wish to know response headers of loading script:

```
date: Sun, 26 Feb 2017 00:00:00 GMT
etag: "хххх"
status: 200
```

Do you know ways to get such data?

Comment: Not sure if this is a true duplicate, but I'd suggest looking at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/220231/accessing-the-web-pages-http-headers-in-javascript (from quick read, seems answer is you can't for the way you're doing it)

Comment: But. It's different.  In that subject It uses ajax, doesn't load a script.

Comment: Hence the not flagging as duplicate but pointing out that the link exists